# ggmap map style repository? Now that CloudMade no longer gives out APIs

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but does anybody have suggestions for accessing different map styles that can be used for ggmap? CloudMade no longer gives API keys to accounts which are not 'enterprise accounts'.

From "ggmap: Spatial Visualization with ggplot2" (Kahle and Wickham), they suggest to either use Stamen or Google maps, but I'm looking for a different style than offered by these.

Can anybody suggest a repository of map styles that could be used for ggmap?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a simple land - water contrast using the `maps` package:

Set the boundaries of the map with xlim and ylim.

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)

map <- fortify(map(fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE))

ggplot(data = map, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group)) +
   geom_polygon(fill = "ivory2") +
   geom_path(colour = "black") +
   coord_cartesian(xlim = c(137, 164), ylim = c(-14, 3.6)) +
   theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#F3FFFF"),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

The map is a bit clunky, but high resolution maps are available in the `mapdata` package>

```
library(mapdata)
map <- fortify(map("worldHires", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE))

ggplot(data = map, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group)) +
   geom_polygon(fill = "ivory2") +
   geom_path(colour = "black") +
   coord_cartesian(xlim = c(135, 165), ylim = c(-15, 0)) +  # Papua New Guinea
   theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#F3FFFF"),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank())  # Be patient
```

Or a single country can be selected.

```
map <- fortify(map("worldHires", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE))

ggplot(data = subset(map, region == "Papua New Guinea"), aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group)) +
   geom_polygon(fill = "ivory2") +
   geom_path(colour = "black") +
   theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#F3FFFF"),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: Revisiting this: using the this solution (which is great!), I'm having difficulty adding points to the map, ie `geom_point(data=newdataset, aes(long, lat))` getting the error message `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'group' not found` any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, missed your comment. Add this line to the `ggplot` command: `geom_point(inherit.aes = FALSE, data = data.frame(long = 145, lat = -6), aes(long, lat), size = 5, colour = "red")`.

Answer (score 2):

Google maps has a little know style feature:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

As another comment noted, get_map is just a wrapper for get_googlemap, etc. And then get_googlemap is just a wrapper for a series of http calls to get map tiles, so it seems possible to hack up the code from get_googlemap a bit so instead of pointing at the basic google map style, it would grab styled tiles.

I may work on this approach over the next month as I have a need for a similar basemap as requested by OP.

Answer (score 2):

> This currently works best with the development version of ggmap. To use this you need to run `devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")`

I have developed a new package `ggmapstyles`, which should help with this problem: https://github.com/mikey-harper/ggmapstyles . It provides an easy way of selecting themes from [Snazzy Maps](https://snazzymaps.com/), which has over 16,000 different styles premade and allows you to create custom designs.

[image]

To use a design, go to Snazzymaps and find a style you like, and then copy the URL into the function `get_snazzymap()` using the `mapRef` argument:

```
devtools::install_github("dr-harper/ggmapstyles")
library(ggmapstyles)

map <- get_snazzymap(center = 'Southampton, UK', 
                     mapRef = "https://snazzymaps.com/style/72543/assassins-creed-iv")
ggmap(map)
```

[image]

Will plan on developing this further, and potentially merge it with ggmap in the future :)

Comment: Your example does not seem to work anymore? I get `Error: max url length is 2048 characters.`

Comment: @Florian  You need to install the development version of ggmaps: https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap . Some styles need a really long URL, and the maximum length has been increased to 8192 characters in the development version

Answer (score 0):

This is the function definition for `get_map`:

```
function (location = c(lon = -95.3632715, lat = 29.7632836), 
    zoom = "auto", scale = "auto", maptype = c("terrain", "satellite", 
        "roadmap", "hybrid", "toner", "watercolor"), messaging = FALSE, 
    urlonly = FALSE, filename = "ggmapTemp", crop = TRUE, color = c("color", 
        "bw"), source = c("google", "osm", "stamen", "cloudmade"), 
    api_key)
```

and, there's a series of `if` statements in it that limit it to the `source = …` options.

You can combine them with the various `maptype = …` options to try to get something that works for you.

Comment: So I guess to reword my question: I'm looking for maptypes other than the ones that are listed above ("terrain", "satellite", "roadmap", "hybrid", "toner", "watercolor"). I'm aware of those map types, looking for other options.

Comment: So, `get_map` ultimately calls `get_googlemap`, `get_stamenmap` or `get_openstreetmap`. The former two functions use `match.arg` to ensure the options to `maptype` match what's in the function definition, and the latter doesn't have a `maptype`. The doc you referenced is fairly exhaustive as to what's "allowed". So, this is ending up being a long way to say "no, there's no other hidden or alternate options".

Comment: I didn't know if openstreetmap had some sort of style bank/repository. Really what I was just looking for was a simple black and white style where the land mass is outlined in black and coloured grey. Thanks anyway!